# Two figures with near-identical code resulting in different-sized pie charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm working with the following dataframe: [example data](https://rentry.co/tn2sk). I'm dividing them by 'type' to create two figures for multiple pie charts, however the figures are resulting in different-sized pie charts (the individual pie charts within each figure) even though the code for both is nearly-identical.

This is the code I'm using to create the pie charts for 'Movie':

```
# filtering it down to 'Movie' and removing redundant value (/category for pie chart)
genre_originals_count_12_movies = genre_originals_count_12[(genre_originals_count_12['type'] == 'Movie') & (genre_originals_count_15['value'] != 'International Movies') & (genre_originals_count_12['value'] != 'Movies')]
    
# defining color dictionary for pie charts
colors_dict_movies_og = {'Dramas': 'skyblue', 'Comedies':'c', 'Action & Adventure':'lightcyan', 'Children & Family Movies':'lightyellow', 
                   'Independent Movies':'deepskyblue', 'Romantic Movies':'mediumseagreen', 'Thrillers':'mediumaquamarine', 
                   'Documentaries':'brown', 'Sci-Fi & Fantasy':'tab:cyan', 'Stand-Up Comedy':'aliceblue', 
                   'Horror Movies':'k', 'Music & Musicals':'lightcoral', 'Sports Movies':'dodgerblue', 'Movies':'mistyrose', 
                   'International Movies':'tan', 'Anime Features':'indianred'}
    
# creating figure/axes with dimensions
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(5*6.5, 3*12), subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
    
# populating figure with pie charts
for ax, (name, sub_df) in zip(axs.ravel(), genre_originals_count_12_movies.groupby('unstacked_country')):
        ax.pie(sub_df['count'], labels=sub_df['value'], colors = [colors_dict_movies_og[x] for x in sub_df['value']], textprops={'fontsize':15})
        ax.set_title(name, size=25)
        
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0.03, 0.05, 0.97, 1])
```

This is the code I'm using to create the pie charts for 'TV Show' is near-identical:

```
genre_originals_count_12_tv = genre_originals_count_12[(genre_originals_count_12['type'] == 'TV Show') & (genre_originals_count_12['value'] != 'International TV Shows')]

colors_dict_tv_og = {'TV Dramas': 'orangered', 'TV Comedies':'firebrick', 'Kids\' TV':'lightcoral', 'Crime TV Shows':'coral', 
               'Docuseries':'red', 'Romantic TV Shows':'tomato', 'Reality TV':'indianred', 
               'British TV Shows':'darkorange', 'Anime Series':'orange', 'TV Action & Adventure':'lightsalmon', 'TV Mysteries': 'mistyrose',
               'Korean TV Shows': 'tan', 'TV Horror':'peachpuff', 'Stand-Up Comedy & Talk Shows': 'rosybrown',
               'Spanish-Language TV Shows':'lemonchiffon', 'TV Sci-Fi & Fantasy':'chocolate', 'TV Thrillers': 'sandybrown',
               'Teen TV Shows':'bisque', 'Science & Nature TV':'brown'}


fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(5*6.5, 3*12), subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})

for ax, (name, sub_df) in zip(axs.ravel(), genre_originals_count_12_tv.groupby('unstacked_country')):
    ax.pie(sub_df['count'], labels=sub_df['value'], colors = [colors_dict_tv_og[x] for x in sub_df['value']], textprops={'fontsize':15})
    ax.set_title(name, size=25)
    
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0.03, 0.05, 0.97, 1])
```

But here is how different the two sets of pie charts look:

[image]

[image]

Why is this and how can I make them the pie charts within the figures the same size?

Comment: Seems pretty clear.  Your second set of pie charts has a lot more and longer text labels.  It had to reduce the size of the charts to make room for the labels.  Perhaps you could use less wordy labels?

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I thought the label size would somehow be standardized when given the same dimensions. Is there a way to do that manually? I unfortunately can't change the label names

Comment: Try increasing your figure width or plot 2 subplots per row instead of 3.

Comment: @papke, I just tried your suggestion (6x2) without changing the dimensions and oddly enough the charts didn't change size (the labels and title did)

Comment: You could remove `tight_layout` and set a larger `wspace` in `plt.subplots(..., gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0.3})`.  `tight_layout` resizes and moves the subplots to fit the texts, resulting in different sizes.

Comment: @JohanC, thank you. This didn't help make the second set larger, but it did help in making the first set of pie charts smaller and more in line the second set.